# How to enable rainbow parentheses in SLIME?

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, slime

I am an Emacs and Common Lisp novice. I have successfully installed SLIME in my Emacs, but I noticed it does not have rainbow parentheses (which comes as a surprise). How do I enable this feature? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seasoned Lisp programmers would find rainbow parens to be a huge nuisance (since [parens are supposed to be "invisible"](http://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/style.txt) (see the Parenthetical Philosophy section)), so from that point of view, the lack of rainbow parens is probably not as much of a surprise as you might think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [Rainbow Delimiters](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RainbowDelimiters) mode over on [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org) which might suit you - otherwise there's a bunch of [other parenthesis appearance packages](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParenthesesAppearance) there as well.

---

Update: This worked for me.
This is probably still not as novice-friendly as it could be. I've had 20 years of on-and-off use to help me forget what being a total Emacs novice is like...

First, make sure there's an `.emacs` file in your home directory. `C-x C-f` [visit-buffer] followed by `~/.emacs` and Enter should do the trick.

You also need a directory to save your elisp files in.
"~/.emacs.d/" is usually on the `load-path`, so using that is the easiest way to get started.
Create it if it doesn't exist.

Next, download [rainbow-delimiters.el](http://github.com/jlr/rainbow-delimiters/raw/master/rainbow-delimiters.el). It should go into your elisp folder from the previous step.
Type `M-x byte-compile-file`, followed by Return, then the path to your rainbow-delimiters.el (this step is only for efficiency).

Now enter the following in your `.emacs`:

```
(require 'rainbow-delimiters)
(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
```

and save (`C-x C-s`) and restart.

(A "mode hook" is a function (or rather list of functions) that is called when Emacs switches to a specific mode.).

If you don't want to restart Emacs just to try it, you can position the cursor at the end of each expression and type `C-x C-e` [eval-last-sexp] (this also works in the interactive "*scratch*" buffer).

Starting slime with `M-x slime` after this gave me coloured parentheses.

The colour scheme is customizable; the easiest way of finding the options is `M-x customize-apropos` (hit Return), type `rainbow` (hit Return).

HTH.

Oh, and look through the built-in tutorial (`C-h t`) if you haven't already. Emacs has a slightly peculiar vocabulary, so reading the documentation (`C-h i`) now and then is good, and there's plenty of "oh, it can do *that*" moments in there.

Comment: I am an Emacs novice. Google searches on the topic led me to the pages you mention, but I couldn't figure out how to get any of that work with SLIME.

Comment: @missingfaktor: Did you get rainbow to work in other modes than Slime? I'm fairly sure the relevant mode hook for Slime is `slime-repl-mode-hook`, in case that's what you're missing.

Comment: I lack the necessary Emacs knowledge to comprehend what you're saying. No, I haven't yet managed to get rainbow working on any other mode. Actually I have no other Lisp mode installed.

Comment: @missingfaktor Did you download rainbow-delimiters.el? Did you place it in your emacs load path, if you don't know what that is, see this: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath Once you have that file installed, following the instructions on emacs wiki should be a breeze.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed steps. I followed them. Now [I am also unable to get SLIME work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291428/slime-connect-not-working), so I can't tell if the rainbow parentheses feature was correctly installed.

Comment: I got SLIME working. And I followed all the steps mentioned here. Yet rainbow feature isn't working for me. :(

Comment: @missingfaktor: Are you sure? My rainbow colour scheme was so unsaturated that I had to squint to see it. (Of course you're sure, I just have no idea what could be going wrong.) Sorry I can't help.

Comment: (Please don't hit me!) All this while I was checking the editor window. The hook however was for REPL. The rainbows were working fine on REPL. Adding `lisp-mode-hook` enabled them for main editor too. Thanks!