# slime-connect not working

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, slime

I am an Emacs and Common Lisp novice. I have successfully installed SLIME in my Emacs, but I am unable to run it. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> `slime-connect` gives the following options, accepting which gives the error pasted below the options.

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 4005

Connecting to Swank on port 4005...
make client process failed: connection refused, :name, SLIME Lisp, :buffer, nil,
                                                :host, 127.0.0.1, :service 4005,
                                                :nowait, nil
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: the usual way using SLIME would be to configure one or more Lisps. Typically then m-x slime will start the pre-defined Lisp and connect to it. Note that you need a Lisp installed - something like SBCL, CLISP, LispWorks, CCL, ...

Comment: @RainerJoswig, I have CLISP installed.

Comment: Have you done `(setq inferior-lisp-program "/path/to/lisp")` somewhere in your init files?  ~/.emacs for example.

Comment: @AndrewMyers, no. I have this though: `(add-hook 'inferior-lisp-mode-hook (lambda () (inferior-slime-mode t)))`.

Comment: AFAIK, `slime-connect` is for connecting to an already executing lisp which is running a swank server. Otherwise set `inferior-lisp-program` to your CLISP path and just do `M-x slime` to start it.

Comment: @AndrewMyers, @molbdnilo, I added this line `(setq inferior-lisp-program "C:/Program Files/clisp-2.49")`. Still not working. :(

Comment: @missingfaktor The path you specified looks like a directory, it should be the full path to the executable to start Lisp.  Also, this is to run `M-x slime`, not sure about `slime-connect`.

Comment: @AndrewMyers, I realized the mistake and changed the path to point to exe. It still didn't work. Turned out the whitespace in `Program Files` was causing a problem. So I moved the clisp directory elsewhere and modified the paths accordingly. It appears to work now.

Comment: @AndrewMyers, after I did `M-x slime`, it has been polling something. It's been five minutes, but it's still stuck at that stage. I don't understand what that means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. to fix the whitespace - escape it with double backward slash.
2. When you do `slime-connect` it will expect a Lisp image (Lisp runtime) to be up and listening on the server and port you connect to. Probably you didn't mean it.
3. `slime` will first launch `inferior-lisp-program`, and then connect to it. This is what you want to do, actually.

https://github.com/quicklisp/quicklisp-slime-helper this is something you might want to try (when you are done with the setup, or instead). Or just keep it for the time you feel more comfortable with more setup. The program in the link is a helper, that works through quicklisp - something you might want to get familiar with, a kind of package manager for Lisp code, and SLIME you run in Emacs. Possibly, if you will find that it is easier for you to

- first install the Lisp you want.
- install quicklisp. (follow the instructions here: http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/ with the exception that for Windows you might either use Cygwin, or instead of curl, just right-click on the link and do the "save target as" voodoo magic :). If you don't use SBCL, then --load may not be an option for your lisp. Replace it with something like: start your Lisp, type into REPL: `(load "quicklisp.lisp")`, provided your current working directory is the one where you saved the quicklisp.lisp file. To print out the current directory, if not sure: `(directory ".")`.
- Read the README for quicklisp-slime-helper and follow the instructions in it. Basically, there's only one thing you want to configure after you install it via quicklisp, it is:

  (load "c:/full-path-to/quicklisp/slime-helper.el")

in the .emacs file.

If you aren't familiar with *nix path names, tilde means the current user's home directory, aka `$HOME`, you probably set it up as an environment variable when you installed Emacs. Note that `quicklisp-slime-helper` and `slime` packages are mutually exclusive (it's the same package, just wrapped differently), so if you have something like:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/slime")
(require 'slime)
```

Then, if you want to use the `quicklisp-slime-helper`, comment that away, and use only the configuration for one of them.

PS. Re'

```
(add-hook 'inferior-lisp-mode-hook (lambda () (inferior-slime-mode t)))
```

This looks redundant, why do you need that / what is that? Where did you get `inferior-slime-mode`? That's something that doesn't look familiar to me. What happens if you position the point (caret) on it and hit <kbd>C-h f</kbd>?

Comment: Thanks. There were a couple of issues - whitespace in path name of Lisp executable, and CLISP. Changing to a different directory and using SBCL solved those problems.

Comment: Re: `(add-hook 'inferior-lisp-mode-hook (lambda () (inferior-slime-mode t)))`, I copied it from somewhere. Emacs still works after I comment that line out. On <kbd>C-h f</kbd> it gives me "Describe function", and when I enter the name, it says no match found.